# Rfid module on nodemcu

Tags: nodemcu

I am trying to connect a mfrc522 module with nodemcu. I have tried all tutorials available in youtube. Everytime it shows firmware version: 0x89 (unknown}.

Comment: Can you assume that no one else has tried all the tutorials on youtube, and post your code and how you have it hooked up in your particular situation?

Comment: What exactly did you do that resulted in the error to occur. And where does it show "firmware version: 0x89 (unknown}"

Comment: well, the "valid" versions of mfrc522 (at least according to the MFRC522 library) are 0x88 for the Fudan Semiconductor FM17522 clone, 0x90 for MFRC522 firmware 0.0, 0x91 for MFRC522 firmware 1.0 and 0x92 for MFRC522 firmware 2.0 - 0x89 is not known in that library, and therefore that library won't deal with it - use the `PCD_DumpVersionToSerial` to see if your device is supported

Comment: Please post an actual question. So what that the firmware version is 89?

Comment: My device has a rc522 chip manufactured by nxp. Pcd_dumpverisontoserial shows the version as 0x89. I have done some projects with both nodemcu and arduino. So i am sure about the connections.